# Read/Copy iphone contacts from PC using C#

Tags: c#, iphone, contacts

Can anybody guide me How to read contacts from iphone from PC using C# application.

Recently, I had used Mobiledevice.dll from http://mobiledevice.codeplex.com/.
You can retrieve its model, serial number, version, firmware information, jailbroken status, and much more.

But there is no api to Read Address book of iPhone device(The contacts are stored in a SQLite database at this location: /private/var/mobile/Library/AddressBook/AddressBook.sqlitedb).
 Don,t know how to copy this AddressBook.sqlitedb file to PC.

I know this is possible, there are number of desktop applications which are doing same task like iFunbox, iExplorer, http://www.iphone-to-pc.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add these code in viewDidLoad:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook =ABAddressBookCreate();

CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople (addressBook);

CFArrayRef allGroups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);

for (id person in (NSArray *) allPeople)
[self logContact:person];

for (id group in (NSArray *) allGroups)
[self logGroup:group];

CFRelease(allGroups);

CFRelease(allPeople);

CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Then create a AddressBook.ABAddressBook CopyArrayOfAllPeople and ABAddressBook CopyArrayOfAllGroups can read all info.
Now you can output the contacts to console via logPerson and logGroup.

More reviews:http://www.softwarebbs.com/wiki/Main_Page